# Auto Pass data value MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am fairly new to MVC and .net. Pardon me if I couldn't phrase/explain my question well.

Everytime user generate an exercise, instead of auto generating TRExNumber as 1 2 3 4 5, I wish to auto generate this TRExNumber in a determined fashion. However, I don't know where I should "code it"

```
[Table("TREx")]
public class TrExModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Trade Exercise")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TRExNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Could anyone hit me where I should code my "condition" please.

Thank you very much and I apologize for this stupid question.

Comment: That column is identity and that's why is getting autogenerated with numbers 1,2,3,etc. But if you remove the decorator you'd also have to update database and the rest of your application accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I can change that, I wish to have it autogenerated but not in identity fashion

Comment: Which kind of number format you want to achieve? Identity column by default autogenerate its value starting from 1, you can set it to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` then implement your custom identity value logic in class constructor.